# How to connect points with zero value in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

Highcharts can connect a series line between null values, but it appears that it cannot connect a line between points with value of 0 if the yAxis min is also set to 0. Is there a workaround?

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/p2EYM/2/

What the chart looks like (note breaks in line):

[image]

and the Highcharts code:

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    title: {
        text: 'Points with zero value are not connected by line'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        offset: 10,
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            connectNulls: true
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
         min: 0,
    },
    series: [{
        data: [20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 40, 50, 10, null, null, 0, 0]
    }]

});
});
```

Comment: Figured out one potential workaround: add a small negative yAxis.min value, and set yAxis.startOnTick = false. See http://jsfiddle.net/p2EYM/4/

Comment: that's exactly right, the line that connects the 0 values does actually exist in your current implementation it's just that it's covered by the X axis.  So a small negative yAxis min value fixes that.

Comment: @RealityExtractor - it'd sure make it easier if the line could be displayed on top of the X axis. The amount of negative yAxis min adjustment required changes with the max value of the series.